# SELECT * FROM (SELECT)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

There is a table "MAIN_TABLE" with columns "Table_Unique_Code" and "Table_name".

Also there are several tables with required data.

The task is to create SQL-query with parameter ("Table_Unique_Code"), which will select all data from the table determined by the "Table_Unique_code".

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM (*determine the name of the table by Table_Unique_code  here*);
```

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT table_name FROM MAIN_TABLE WHERE Table_Unique_Code=?)
```

but it doesn't work.

I work with OracleDB.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: You should look at Dynamic SQL

Comment: Try to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` ;).

Comment: @JohnHC I updated the question with the query I tried to use. Can you tell me what's wrong with it, and how to determine table_name from MAIN_TABLE by Table_Unique_Code dynamically? Thank you

Comment: You cannot do this in a query. You will have to use a dynamic SQL procedure/script.

Comment: To clarify John's answer: When you send a query to the server, all the table names involved must be known beforehand - they can't be determined at execution time. In particular, the table name cannot be a bind variable, and it can't be a string read from a table only when the query is executed. Your attempt failed because what you want to do simply **cannot** be done. And don't let the name "dynamic SQL" fool you into thinking it's just some simple extension of "standard" SQL; it isn't, it's something very different and almost always recommended **against**.

Comment: Your entire setup is uncommon, inefficient, and open to many opportunities for human error and malicious acts. Why do you have this unhealthy arrangement and this task to begin with?

Comment: @mathguy Thank you for such a detailed commentary! This definitely clarified a lot in my mind:)